# Invisible/Conditional link to draft pages

Tags: wordpress

While writing new blog posts I occasionally hit keywords, that I want to write an other post in the future about. The post didn't exist right now, but creating a link (or anything that will become a link later) while writing the post, would make it a lot easier to reference to the future post than adding links later manually when the new post really exists.

I already thought about using drafts for this scenario and just create an empty post, but I couldn't find a plugin for displaying conditional invisible links to draft and visible links to finally published posts.

Any ideas how to address this issue?

Comment: Define an "invisible link"?

Comment: Anything that is not clickable by a visitor and might lead to a 404. In best case this is plain text if the target is still a draft and a real link as soon as the target is published.

Comment: Actually I can't believe that I'm the first one who run into this issue?